# Reduce Windows partition even if already used?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

so I have a kinda old desktop computer(well 4GB RAM) with Windows XP on it, so im considering installing Ubuntu for now on it,and have a dual boot(Windows-Ubuntu).I started parted magic on the desktop pc to check what were the partition to see what they were and here what I got:

http://s29.postimg.org/pm7romadz/IMG_2828.jpg

the entire(well 99%) of the disk is a single NTFS partition that has windows XP on it.So I am wondering if its possible to decrease the NTFS partition to create a new one for ubuntu, even if windows XP is on this partition? Because it says theres still 111GB unused in the partition?Is there any risk to corrupt Windows XP if I do this?

thank you!

Comment: Shrinking a partition will not corrupt the installation

Comment: so I can shrink it as much I want as long as its in the free NTFS partition space(unused space)?

Answer (score 2):

There's *ALWAYS* a risk of damage to a disk; even just powering it up poses some risk. Filesystem resizing operations *usually* succeed, but they do add to the risk compared to normal use, particularly if you move the start sector of the partition.

Speaking of which, GParted in Linux may move the start sector of the partition, even if you don't explicitly tell it to do so. This will render Windows unbootable. Thus, you should probably not use GParted to resize your partition. (This risk is greatly reduced with newer versions of Windows, but that's another matter....)

Your best bet is to resize the partition using Windows tools. Modern versions of Windows have standard disk-partitioning programs that can do the job, but I don't recall if that feature is present in Windows XP. If so, you should be able to launch the Windows Disk Utility (or whatever it's called) and resize away. *Do not* create new partitions for Linux, though; leave that task to the Linux installation tools. If XP's disk partitioning tools lack the ability to resize, you'll have to rely on a third-party program. I have no specific recommendations on this, since I'm not familiar with the pros and cons of most Windows partitioning tools.

Comment: I upvoted this as I agree with most of it - I do not, however, agrew with the last Paragraph - specifically it is often OK to create partitions under Linux.

Comment: The text reads "*Do not* create new partitions ***FOR*** Linux" (emphasis added). The trouble is that the standard Windows partitioning tool is pretty dreadful and is likely to mess up the task of creating Linux partitions. The worst problem is that it sometimes converts to a [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) setup, although I believe that problem began with Vista or 7 and so probably doesn't apply to XP. Back when it was current, I recall a lot of stories of Windows XP's partitioner creating damaged partition tables.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP *(agh, stop using that antique, people; it's insecure, unsupported, and doesn't know what to do with modern hardware anyhow)* does not support shrinking mounted volumes and may not support shrinking volumes at all. I've had success in the past using parted (through GUI tools like GParted or QTParted) in Linux, but I also recently ran across a huge bug in parted *(though it only matters to GPT disks, which XP is so archaic it probably flat-out can't read)* so I'm a little leery of that program right now.

The safest way to resize the partition in a Windows-friendly way would be to boot from the install media from Vista or newer, as they support shrinking NTFS volumes and are probably safer at it. Tell Windows Setup that you want to do a clean install, and when it asks you what partition to install to you will be able to shrink the existing partition. You can cancel Setup after shrinking that partition (and optionally creating a new one in the freed space). Alternatively, detach the hard drive, connect it to a computer running a modern version of Windows, and use Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`) or the command-line `diskpart` tool to shrink the partition.

It may also help to defragment the drive before trying to shrink it, as this will tend to move stuff towards the front of the disk, freeing up space at the back. Unfortunately, XP likes to put the pagefile somewhere pretty far down the partition, and that can't be moved while the OS is booted unless you turn off use of the pagefile in Windows.

Oh, and you'd think this wouldn't be necessary, but: **Shut the OS down fully before trying to resize the volume; don't attempt it while the machine is hibernated!** The results of that were pretty funny, but that didn't make it a good idea.